# Sending both html and css file on the res.sendfile express js

Tags: html, css, node.js, express

I am not able to send both css and html file on the res.sendfile in express.js.

**index.html**

```
    <div class="hdngTab">
    <h1 style="align-content: center">Automation Utility</h1>
    </div>
```

**index.css**

```
    .hdngTab{
    background-color: rgb(60, 120, 120);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:  solid rgb(60, 120, 120);
    text-align: center
    }
```

**index.js**

```
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const http = require("http").Server(app).listen(3000);

    console.log("Server Started");

    app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    }
    )
```

I tried below options based on some online references, but nothing helped me out:

1. Passed *index.css* on the root as the browser should able to load it by own.

   ```
   app.get('/index.css', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "index.html");
   });
   ```
2. Created new folder and moved my static files (*html and css)* under that folder and replaced *res.sendfile* with *app.use(express.static("folderName"));*

Any other possible option to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `express.static` to server static files like:

Suppose your folder structure:

```
app.js
|    +-- public
|    |   +-- css
|    |   |   +-- mystyle.css
```

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// using express you don't need this
// const http = require("http").Server(app).listen(3000);

// server your css as static
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'))

console.log("Server Started");

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

// start your server
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started at port 3000'))
```

In your html

```
<link href="css/mystyle.css"
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyother thing remains the same except this line -

// server your css as static
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));`